# FFmpeg ignores scaling options

Tags: ffmpeg

So far i have this command to generate thumbnails from input video:

```
ffmpeg -ss 3 -i C:\\temp\\5.mp4 -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4),scale=w=320:h=240:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease" -frames:v 3 -vsync vfr -vf fps=fps=1/100 5%02d.jpg
```

based on this question:

https://superuser.com/questions/538112/meaningful-thumbnails-for-a-video-using-ffmpeg

However output images are equal to input video dimensions (ffmpeg ignores passed scale config)

Comment: The fps filter has to be added in the same filterchain as the select and scale

Comment: @Gyan moving fps in there will changes the resulting images (which is not desirable).

Comment: Neither the select nor the scale have any effect at present. If you want to apply all 3 filters in the order shown in your current command, then my above comment stands. If you only want the frames selected by fps then add the scale after the fps and drop the first vf